# Cannot make parsley-trigger work

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

I'm trying to implement Parsley.js form validation to a simple form. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Load the JS -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.2/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="parsley.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
body {
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}
form {
margin: 0;
}
input.parsley-success {
color: #468847 !important;
background-color: #DFF0D8 !important;
border: 1px solid #D6E9C6 !important;
}
input.parsley-error {
color: #B94A48 !important;
background-color: #F2DEDE !important;
border: 1px solid #EED3D7 !important;
}
input {
width: 150px;
margin: 0 2px !important;
}
ul.parsley-error-list {
font-size: 11px;
margin: 2px;
list-style-type:none;
}
ul.parsley-error-list li {
line-height: 11px;
}
h3 {
color: #FB4006;
}
</style>
<body>
<h3>JS Validation: Parsley.js</h3>
<form parsley-validate>
<p><input type="text" parsley-type="email" parsley-trigger="keyup" parsley-validation-minlength="0" placeholder="keyup validation trigger" /><p>
<p><input type="text" parsley-type="email" parsley-trigger="change" parsley-validation-minlength="0" placeholder="change validation trigger" /></p>
<input type="checkbox" name="mincheckdemo[]" parsley-mincheck="2" value="foo" parsley-trigger="change" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mincheckdemo[]" value="bar" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mincheckdemo[]" value="baz" />
</form> 
</body>
```

It is nearly the same as the example of "parsley-trigger". However I cannot make it work properly, that's to say, enter some text and see the validation result immediately or after focus-out. I'd like to know why.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that parsley is active on the form, and that something hasn't gone wrong referencing your local `parsley.js`? Perhaps the path/location is not what you think it is.

Also, the first input field has `<p>` at the end instead of `</p>`.

EDIT: [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkFqz/) which shows the code working.

EDIT2: The fiddle no longer works because the link to http://rawgithub.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/master/parsley.js is broken.

**This solution refers to version 1 of parsley.js, which has now been superseded by version 2.**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still using Parsley V1 - I fixed this by using `data-type` as opposed to `parsley-type`.
The [v1 documentation](http://parsleyjs.github.io/Parsley-1.x/documentation.html) uses `parsley-type` - Dev is no longer supporting parsley V1.